# JQuery Click Function working for just one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery click method to show and hide a part of my sections after clicking on a certain part of the page .

My HTML code:

```
<section class="apply_section text-center center-block" id="apply_section">
      <div class="apply_container">

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row apply_row">

            <div class="col-md-8 apply_form">
              <form class="form" action="mail.php" method="POST">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" required="required" name="firstName">
                  </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <form class="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="" required="required" name="message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                  <input class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value=""></input>
                </div>

              </form>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 apply_image">
              <a><img src="images/icon.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </section>
```

The jQuery script :

```
$('#apply_section .apply_image a').click(function(){
  if($('#apply_section .apply_form').css('display','none')) {
    $('#apply_section .apply_form').css('display','inline-block');
  }else {$('#apply_section .apply_form').css('display','none');}
});
```

The problem is that the clicking method take the order just for one time, If I click on the image the form will appear, but after that if I need to hide it again and clicking the image doesn't work!

Comment: instead of `if($('#apply_section .apply_form').css('display','none'))` use `if($('#apply_section .apply_form').css('display') == 'none')`...better way to do this is to use jquery `.toggle()` function.

Comment: ... or create a class and use [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: Thanks @kartikeya Khosta, It worked . What a silly mistake :D

Comment: Also I'll try the other choice you are suggesting .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you check css property.

```
$('#apply_section .apply_image a').click(function() {
  if ($('#apply_section .apply_form').css('display') == 'none') { // Here, check if display value is 'none'
    $('#apply_section .apply_form').css('display', 'inline-block');
  } else {
    $('#apply_section .apply_form').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

Comment: What a shame to make such a mistake!:D  Thaks a lot @Oen44 it worked as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using toggle:

```
 $('#apply_section .apply_image a').click(function() {
     var boolean = $('#apply_section .apply_form').css('display') == 'none';
      $('#apply_section .apply_form').toggle(boolean)
 });
```

According to Jquery toggle docs:
`The matched elements will be revealed or hidden immediately, with no animation, by changing the CSS display property. If the element is initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown. The display property is saved and restored as needed. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.`

Comment: `toggle` returns `display: block`, when OP is using `inline-block`.

Comment: @Oen44 - The main purpose was to hide or show the element. Wasn't it?

Comment: But there is a difference between `block` and `inline-block` display which can affect page look.

Comment: @Oen44: According to Jquery documentation: `The matched elements will be revealed or hidden immediately, with no animation, by changing the CSS display property. If the element is initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown. The display property is saved and restored as needed. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.`

Comment: You are damn right, what a stupid mistake... Please make small edit to you post so I can change vote.

Comment: @Oen44: No problem! We are here to help!

Answer (score -1):

A better way to do something like that is using a toggle to a class:

CSS

```
.hide {
    display:none; 
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#apply_section .apply_image a').click(function(){
        $('#apply_section .apply_form').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: No tag `css` included and OP didn't say about using CSS, don't post answers not related with OP question.

Answer (score -1):

Simplify your code using toggle():

```
$('#apply_section .apply_image a').click(function(){
    $('#apply_section .apply_form').toggle();
});
```